# How do I deserialize nested JSON data into a flattened object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using Json.NET to deserialize incoming json data into an object, but I want to flatten one of the a nested data into a property as an array.

What my incoming json data looks like:

```
{
   “sets": {
        "set": [
            {
                "name": "Act 1:",
                “title”: [
                    {
                        "name": “A”
                    },
                    {
                        "name": “B”
                    },
                    {
                        "name": “C”
                    },
                    {
                        "name": “D”
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Act 2:",
                “title”: [
                    {
                        "name": “E”
                    },
                    {
                        "name": “F”
                    },
                    {
                        "name": “G”
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I want the transformed data to look like when object is serialized:

```
{
   “sets": {
       “title”: [
              {
                  "name": “A”
              },
              {
                  "name": “B”
              },
              {
                  "name": “C”
              },
              {
                  "name": “D”
              },
              {
                  "name": “E”
              },
              {
                  "name": “F”
              },
              {
                  "name": “G”
              }
         ]
    }
}
```

What approach can I take to achieve this? Is it possible to customize how my object gets deserialized?

Comment: What's the goal?  To have an c# object that looks like the json result?  Or an actual json result?  Does it have to be a part of the deserialization process?   How about a method that converts it?

Comment: Please show your class

Comment: Yes, the goal is to get a c# object that looks like the result. It would be neat to have this be a part of the deserialization process! I currently have nested foreach loops to get to all the "name"s, and would like to remove this foreach loop if possible! @Tyddlywink

Comment: You could get an anonymous class with the result format through a linq statement.  Or make a result class and use that.

Comment: Will it work if you deserialize it into an object, create a new object with a different class by removing all second instances of "name" and "title", and serialize again?

Comment: @MiguelMateo I guess that is one way. I was just trying to figure out how to reduce the number of steps I need to get to my desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you are asking for it to be done in the deserialization but this gives the same results.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/U89KwW

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{



    public const string Json = "{\"sets\": {\"set\": [{\"name\": \"Act 1:\",\"title\": [{\"name\":\"A\"},{\"name\": \"B\"},{\"name\": \"C\"},{\"name\": \"D\"}]},{\"name\": \"Act 2:\",\"title\": [{\"name\": \"E\"},{\"name\": \"F\"},{\"name\": \"G\"}]}]}}";


    public static void Main()
    {

        Something something = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Something>(Json); 

        something.Titles = something.sets.set.SelectMany(c=> c.title).ToList();

        something.sets = null;
        string JsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(something);
        Console.WriteLine(JsonResult);
    }
}

public class Something
{
    public Sets sets {get;set;}


    public List<Title> Titles {get;set;}
}



public class Sets
{
    public List<Set> set {get;set;}


}

public class Set
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public List<Title> title {get;set;}
}

public class Title
{
    public string name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Technically this can be the least efficient approach, but it is often the quickest to design and maintain in the future, so this has the lowest cost to implement. Make sure you don't include fields in the interim model that you do not need in the final output.